# how to pass the json values to rating control in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

here is my stack view code where I had got this code from apple developer site in this rating control was manually giving but I am having the data coming from web services how to pass to the rating control to display the stars as got from the web services can anyone help me ?

```
    var number = 0

    private var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()

    var rating = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateButtonSelectionStates()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var starSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 10.0) {
        didSet {
            setupButtons()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var starCount: Int = 5 {
        didSet {
            setupButtons()
        }
    }

    //MARK: Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButtons()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupButtons()
    }

    //MARK: Button Action

    func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        guard let index = ratingButtons.index(of: button) else {
            fatalError("The button, \(button), is not in the ratingButtons array: \(ratingButtons)")
        }

        // Calculate the rating of the selected button
        let selectedRating = index + 1

        if selectedRating == rating {
            // If the selected star represents the current rating, reset the rating to 0.
            rating = 0
        } else {
            // Otherwise set the rating to the selected star
            rating = selectedRating
        }
    }


    //MARK: Private Methods

    private func setupButtons() {

        // Clear any existing buttons
        for button in ratingButtons {
            removeArrangedSubview(button)
            button.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        ratingButtons.removeAll()

        // Load Button Images
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let filledStar = UIImage(named: "filledStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)
        let emptyStar = UIImage(named:"emptyStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)


        for index in 0..<starCount {
            // Create the button
            let button = UIButton()

            // Set the button images
            button.setImage(emptyStar, for: .normal)
            button.setImage(filledStar, for: .selected)

            // Add constraints
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: starSize.height).isActive = true
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: starSize.width).isActive = true

            // Set the accessibility label
            button.accessibilityLabel = "Set \(index + 1) star rating"
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            // Setup the button action
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(starRatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            // Add the button to the stack
            addArrangedSubview(button)

            // Add the new button to the rating button array
            ratingButtons.append(button)
        }

        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }

    private func updateButtonSelectionStates() {
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerated() {
            // If the index of a button is less than the rating, that button should be selected.
            button.isSelected = index < rating

            // Set accessibility hint and value
            let hintString: String?
            if rating == index + 1 {
                hintString = "Tap to reset the rating to zero."
            } else {
                hintString = nil
            }

            let valueString: String
            switch (rating) {
            case 0:
                valueString = "No rating set."
            case 1:
                valueString = "1 star set."
            default:
                valueString = "\(rating) stars set."
            }

            button.accessibilityHint = hintString
            button.accessibilityValue = valueString
        }
    }
```

this is my json response where I am getting the data from url in view controller

```
 func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                if let detailsArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail") as? NSArray {
                    for item in detailsArray {
                    if let detailDict = item as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = detailDict.value(forKey: "productName") {
                            self.productName.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let image1 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image1"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image1 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image2 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image2"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image2 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image3 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image3"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image3 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image4 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image4"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image4 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image5 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image5"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image5 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image6 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image6"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image6 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image7 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image7"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image7 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image8 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image8"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image8 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image9 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image9"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image9 as! String)
                        }
                        if let image10 = detailDict.value(forKey: "image10"){
                            self.imageArray.append(image10 as! String)
                        }
                        if let price = detailDict.value(forKey: "productPrice") {
                            self.productprice.append(price as! String)
                        }
                        if let image = detailDict.value(forKey: "img"){
                            self.imagesArray.append(image as! String)
                        }
                        if let review = detailDict.value(forKey: "productReview"){
                            self.reviewArray.append(review as! Int)
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.navigationBar.topItem?.title = self.productName[0]
                    self.priceLabel?.text = self.productprice[0]
                    self.nameLabel?.text = self.productName[0]
                    let x = self.reviewArray[0]
                    var mystring = String(x) + " Reviews"
                    self.reviewLabel.text = mystring
                    let star = starRatingControl()
                    star.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    star.rating = self.reviewArray[0]
                    print(star.rating)
                    self.view.addSubview(star)
                    let imgURL = NSURL(string:self.imageArray[0])
                    let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as URL?)!)
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set the number of stars programmatically?

Comment: no how to pass the values coming from json to the stack view to fill the stars @Spads

Comment: Without knowing structure of your json and where it is loaded not sure how this can answered. You gave us loads of detailed info about how your ratings control is built which is irrelevant. You need to restructure your question.

Comment: @Vamsi Where you are initializing this ratingView show the code for it also show the code where you are getting your JSON response

Comment: @Vamsi What you getting console log for this `print(star.rating)` ?

Comment: I am getting my json passed value that is review rating value

Comment: I need to display the no. of stars that I got from json review rating

Comment: @Vamsi try to changed line `let star = starRatingControl()` to `let star = starRatingControl(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 30, width: 100, height: 30))` means give some specific frame to your star view may be this is the issue

Comment: no this is not the issue